# Alternatives to Streaminsight in the .NET world

Tags: sql-server, streaminsight

Streaminsight was released as part of SQL Server R2, kind of a strange departure but interesting concept. However, it doesnt appear to be anything particularly groundbreaking so I wondered if there were any existing open source .NET libraries that could be considered alternatives to StreamInsight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [NEsper](http://esper.codehaus.org/about/nesper/nesper.html) it is a porting from java's Esper.

Comment: While open source, it is a GPL license

Comment: Non-GPL license is available though for commercial entities.